# Is there a php script that allows me to show every var registered with apc and edit them?

Tags: php, apc

I wanna have the possibility to edit and or delete values of stored variables with `apc_store`.

Is there a script already done for it?

Especially I need to have the possibility to delete some keys of an array stored.

I can't use apc_delete because I need to allow other users who can't inject code to be able to edit cache.

Thanks all

Comment: Why not just use apc_delete? http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.apc-delete.php

Comment: because variable name can be dynamic and/or I need to give this possibility without having to write code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is no. it doesn't exist

I am going to make one if time will love me

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [APCIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.apciterator.php).

Comment: No, I just found out about it by searching the manual. Try using it yourself - it doesn't look hard.

Comment: yes I guess I will have to make one. maybe I will put it on github